# How to open non android sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

There are many explainations how to open Android sqlite database. However how to open non android sqlite database? In particular when opeing database using `SQLiteOpenHelper` I have to give the expected database version. For me it's useless.

Can I use directly `SQLiteDatabase` class and its `openDatabase` method?

I want to open database and convert it to my program android database assuming some structure.

Comment: Check : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 2):

> Can I use directly SQLiteDatabase class and its openDatabase method?

Yes.